# Is it possible to move all windows from one space to the other?

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, spaces, mission-control

Is there a way to move all the windows found in one space into another without having to move them one by one?

(This feature was available in Snow Leopard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't at least for now, hope Apple adds more functionality to Mission Control. Although you can move all windows of a particular app between spaces....

Answer (score 6):

You can still do this in OS X Lion.

Move to the space you want to move the application's windows to. Right-click on the application icon in your Dock, select Options and enable "This Desktop" in the sub-menu. All of the windows should now move over to the current space.

Out of interest, how do you do this in Snow Leopard?

Edit: At last, I found a way to do this. Open Mission Control, and left-click and drag the application icon under the application windows to a new space at the top of the screen. You can create a new space entirely, or move all of the windows to an existing space. Hope this helps.

Comment: That moves all windows from one *application* to a particular space. It also does so permanently. The question was how to move all windows from one *space* (regardless of application) to another.

Comment: Good point. I've updated my original answer with a revised solution. Please let me know how you get on.

Comment: Very nice, the edited bit is very helpful. Unfortunately it means you can only do it if the app you want to move is in the current space (as opposed to being able to move an app from another space to the one you're in), but it's a great start, thanks.